# Select rows from table in Php/Mysql based on time or two dates?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

hi i have players table in mysql .

i need to select inactive players who have not played a match for 6 months in the league .

for example ->

```
select * from players where player (matchplayed == true && (in last 6 months condition));
```

i am newbie in mysql

so will like some help how to deal with time .

Comment: Can you please show the create table syntax?

Comment: the sql query is from joomla but i have explained the logic that i just need to find if the player has played any game in last 6 months if not then then he will be labelled inactive . i dont know how to calculate time period of 6 months .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

some thing like this may work:

```
SELECT * from players where player_matchplayed == true
 && lastmatch_played_date > DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

**DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 6 MONTH)** will give you the interval of last six months from current date. Which you can use to check the `lastmatch_playeddate` is greater than it or not.

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 3):

Try it with this query

```
SELECT * FROM players
WHERE matchplayed IS NOT NULL
AND last_match < NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

`last_match` is a mysql DATE field with the last match information
`matchplayed` is either NULL (not played) or another value for already played

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to mysql date / time functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

I think that DATE_SUB will do the job or a DATE_DIFF for comparison.